# The easiest way to download a picture from a web page in an Android application?

Tags: java, android, image, parsing

I want to pick out the last 5 images (including explanatory text) from http://nucleum.tumblr.com/ and display each image on a new page with the ability to navigate between them in an Android app. Can be compared with http://www.appbrain.com/app/elvis-the-comic/se.oscar.elvisthecomic that retrieves images from elvisthecomic.com/

How do I make it? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the HTML is relatively stable, you could retrieve it, look for the tag  and the text under it, and download them. You could use afterwards a Galery to display them

Answer (score 0):

That page has an associated RSS feed in Atom format, at http://nucleum.tumblr.com/rss - that'd be more reliable to work from than scraping the HTML.

You could read some of the excellent RSS-parsing related answers here on SO (E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android) for examples on how to handle that.

You'd then need to download each image; That should be done on a background thread to avoid your whole app freezing up until all the data are loaded. Again, there are some informative threads (no pun intended!) here on SO : [Downloading images in background while showing the listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374228/downloading-images-in-background-while-showing-the-listview)

Good luck!